# PDO Dblib with "declare" in the query returns false

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Let's check this little piece of code:

```
$p = new PDO('dblib:host=HOST;dbname=DBNAME',USER,PASS);
$sql = "
declare @tutu int = 100;
select @tutu [tutu];
";
$stmt = $p->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
var_dump($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

This returns:

bool(false)

Comment: You should add that edit as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use nextRowset();

```
$p = new PDO('dblib:host=HOST;dbname=DBNAME',USER,PASS);
$sql = "
declare @tutu int = 100;
select @tutu [tutu];
";
$stmt = $p->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->nextRowset();
var_dump($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

This returns:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["tutu"]=>
    string(3) "100"
  }
}
```